# RowGuide and UNIQUE KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i need a `GUID` at row level in my table (name column RowGuid)
datatype is uniqueIdentifier.

Do I need also state it as a `UNIQUE KEY` (alternate key)?

Ex:

```
RowGuid uniqueIdentifier UNIQUE KEY
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just one thing you have to remember : **Unique Key column allows only one row having null value.**

```
I dont think because GUID are unique.
```

Comment: unless, of course, you use a **filtered index** (available in SQL Server 2008) which only looks at the non-null values - then the number of NULL values becomes irrelevant...